# Postgres: missing FROM-clause entry for table - SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

good afternoon I have a query that I am not able to show the column of the table (dpa.view_workflowjob_client) column (f_name), when I place (c.f_name) do not select to view the error (missing entry from the FROM clause for the table). see below:

```
select 
wfjc.f_agent_name,
wfjc.f_policy_name,
wfjc.f_workflow_name,
wfjc.f_workflow_jobid,
wfjc.f_status,
wfjc.f_completion_status,
wfjc.f_completion_report,
wfjc.f_starttime,
wfjc.f_endtime,
wfjc.f_missed_clients,
wfjc.f_disabled_clients,
c.f_name

                        from (
                            select *
                            from dpa.view_workflowjob wfj
                            left join
                            (
                                select                                  
                                    c.f_workflowjob_id,
                                    case when count(c.dis) > 0
                                        then count(c.dis)
                                        else null
                                    end f_disabled_clients,
                                    case when count(c.msd) > 0
                                        then count(c.msd)
                                        else null
                                    end f_missed_clients
                                from
                                (
                                    select
                                        f_name,
                                        f_workflowjob_id,
                                        case when f_status = 'disabled'
                                             then 1
                                             else null
                                        end dis,
                                        case when f_status = 'missed'
                                             then 1
                                             else null
                                        end msd
                                    from dpa.view_workflowjob_client 
                                    where f_starttime <= 1606146420 AND f_endtime >= 1605023220
                                ) c                                                         
                                group by c.f_workflowjob_id
                            ) clients
                            on clients.f_workflowjob_id = wfj.f_id
                        ) wfjc
                        where (
    (wfjc.f_starttime <= 1606146420 AND wfjc.f_endtime >= 1605023220 AND ( (wfjc.f_agent_id = '8512813a-5654-4b18-99cc-0e812076e719') ))
    )
```

Comment: Looks to me you have to pull `f_name` up to `select  c.f_workflowjob_id, f_name, ...`.

Comment: when I put it in error "
ERROR: the column "c.f_name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 8: f_name, "

Comment: Oops I missed the `GROUP BY`.  The easy solution would be to add `c.f_name` to the `GROUP BY`. This would only work though if `c.f_name` had a one to one relationship to `c.f_workflowjob_id`, otherwise your grouping would be off. If there is not a one to one then I'm not sure how to go as the grouping on `c.f_workflowjob_id` will lose the `c.f_name` distinctions.